# Git pull and fetch is not updating one of my branches

Tags: git, github

I have two branches on remote and I'm only working on the 'trampo' branch with a friend:

```
git branch -a
   master
 * trampo
   remotes/origin/master
   remotes/origin/trampo
```

doing a git fetch and git pull is not retrieving the work done yesterday on the 'trampo' branch... how am I supposed to do this?

(I tried the git --track, and checkout on remotes/origin/trampo creates this detached head state that does not seem to hold changes, I dont want to create a new branch too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the remote tracking branch:

```
git branch -u origin/trampo
```

For more information see: [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: It worked.. I thought that just creating and pushing the branch to upstream would already set it to track. Thanks gregor.